# Deserializing XML from API in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-deserialization

I'm building a asp.net MVC program that will consume a xml-based API using httpclient and deserializing it into object using XmlSerializer. 

But got an error : There is an error in XML document (1, 2).

Inner exception: {"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Models'> was not expected."}
My suspicion is somehow I messed up the model class, but I'm not sure.
Thanks!

XML from API:

```
<ArrayDTO xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestService.Models">
  <LaborDTO>
    <CreateDate>2014-04-09T09:20:15.57</CreateDate>
    <CreateUser>test</CreateUser>
  </LaborDTO>
  <LaborDTO>
    <CreateDate>2014-04-09T09:20:15.57</CreateDate>
    <CreateUser>test</CreateUser>
  </LaborDTO>
</ArrayDTO>
```

Below is my C# code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
....
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(serviceString).Result;
....
XmlSerializer ds = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayDTO));
var obj = ds.Deserialize(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
ArrayDTO data = (ArrayDTO) obj;
foreach (var item in ArrayDTO.collection) {
....
}
```

this my model class:

```
public class LaborDTO
{
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
}

public class ArrayDTO
{
    [XmlAttribute("xmlns")]
    public string schema { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("LaborDTO")]
    public LaborDTO[] collection { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is using the  Xml namespace

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestService.Models")]
public class ArrayDTO
{
    [XmlElement("LaborDTO")]
    public LaborDTO[] collection { get; set; }
}
```